# How to handle HTTP timeout?

Tags: java, android, json, http, rest

In my application, I am downloading JSON data from a ReST web service. Most of the time, this works fine, however sometimes the connection will time out.

This is the code I use to set the timeout...

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout( httpParameters, 20000 );
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout( httpParameters, 42000 );
```

If the connection times out, the application crashes and closes, how do I handle a time out?

Comment: Simple put `try-catch` block and catch the TimeOut.

Comment: The connection timeout throws "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected" and the socket timeout "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed out". so try catch

Comment: You need to accept VM's Answer it was his idea.

Answer (score 7):

The HttpClient class throws a ConnectTimeoutException Exception, so you should listen for it:

```
try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    // do something with response
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Timeout", e);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, " Socket timeout", e);
    }
```

Comment: Corrected it to catch both.

Comment: gotta catch'em all

Answer (score 3):

Increase your time of waiting for response like :

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout( httpParameters, 60000 ); //1 minute
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout( httpParameters, 90000 ); // 1.5 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to catch a variety of exception types, I have found that catching an IOException worked as I wanted!

Comment: That's because SocketTimeoutException is a SubType of IOException. :)